# Is race condition possible in Javascript? (e.g.: I want to get and set value atomically)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, atomic, race-condition

I did a lot of searching but still cannot figure it out.

It's simple, a global variable has initial value of `false`;

```
var globalVar = false;
```

`setTimeout` is used twice to call the same function:

```
function(){
    if(!globalVar){
        globalVar = true;
        alert('show only once');
    }
}
```

So is `alert` called only once? Or race condition is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in your case. Javascript is run in a single threaded environment. One of your timeouts will execute completly before the other is able to execute, meaning that when the other executes, it will see that `globalVar` is `true`.

The only concurrency issues that can happen is if you wait for IO, a timeout, or something like that. At that point, other javascript is allowed to execute. No code will ever interrupt other code in order to execute.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function () { alert('hi!'); }, 1000);
while(true) {}
```

You will never see the alert since the while loop will busy wait, chomping up the javascript thread for the other code and never giving the timeout an opportunity to execute.

Comment: I'll remove it, but it fits the Wikipedia definition of a race condition (which is what the asker was wondering about) if the programmer always expected their alert to say 6.

Comment: I was just mentioning that they asked about a race condition (which i categorize as a"concurrency issue" in my mind, even if the code in question isn't really run concurrently... This categorization of mine could be swayed) being possible in JavaScript, so I thought an example if creating the equivalent of a race condition where the result of something depends on an exact sequence of events (in this case, the ajax request taking <500ms) would be helpful for understanding.

Comment: I've had situations where a page assumed that, for example, an AJAX request spawned by changing a textbox (for a search) would come back before the next AJAX request created by changing that same box (i.e. the search for the previous term took longer to execute than the search for the next term). You end up with the search results displayed for the previous search term if you don't put some sort of interlock to verify that the results either are displayed in order or are discarded so that the latest result is always displayed, even if the previous result completes after it.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's a valid exemple and I had to deal with that issue before. Usually, I only aborted previous requests. All right, you win ;)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded, so I don't believe this is possible.